# ¿Cómo crear un mensaje de confirmación de un formulario?

Tags: javascript, alertdialog

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cuál es la función o el código para que se envíe el formulario si le doy en aceptar y no envíe nada si le doy en cancelar?

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<input type="button" name="process" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="pregunta()" value="<?php echo __("Terminar Orden de Compra"); ?>" >

<script language="JavaScript"> 
    function pregunta(){ 
       if(confirm('Son correctos los datos?, BANCO: <?php echo $banco; ?>    CUENTA: <?php echo $cuenta; ?>    CLABE:     ¿Deseas terminar?')){
           return false; } 
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Cómo estás mostrando ese mensaje a través del código? ¿Con un alert? ¿Puedes poner esa parte del código, para ver cómo lo estás haciendo?

Comment: Si quieres que te muestre el botón de Aceptar y Cancelar usa la función "confirm()". Sin embargo mencionas que quieres saber como enviar los datos de tu formulario, muestra tu código para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     <input type="submit" name="process" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Confirmar(event)" value="<?php echo __("Terminar Orden de Compra"); ?>" >

                <script language="JavaScript"> 
function Confirmar(e){
var mensaje = "Son correctos los datos?,  BANCO:<?php echo $banco; ?>        CUENTA:<?php echo $cuenta; ?>            CLABE: <?php echo $clabe; ?>   ¿Deseas terminar?";

    if (!confirm(mensaje)){
    e.preventDefault();
}}

</script>
```

con preventDefault() se solucionaba , muchas gracias a todos

Answer (score 3):

Podrías ejecutar el siguiente código:

```js
function Confirmar(){
    var retVal = confirm("¿Seguro desea continuar?");
    if( retVal == true ){
        document.write ("OK, REGISTRO ALMACENADO");
        return true;
    }else{
        document.write ("NO SE GUARDÓ EL REGISTRO");
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="button" value="PROCEDER" onclick="Confirmar();" />
</form>
```

Con esto guardas en una variable lo que el usuario seleccionó, y según eso ejecutas el código que necesites. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que el evento al que escuchas sea el `submit` en lugar del `click` sobre el botón, debido a que si devuelves un valor falso en el `submit` éste será detenido (no ejecutado) y por tanto no se enviará nada.

El siguiente *snippet* lo ejemplifica.

```js
/**
 * @returns boolean   true sí el usuario confirma los datos.
 */
function pregunta() {
  return confirm('¿Confirma los datos?');
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return pregunta()" action="/">
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" name="process" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="pregunta()" value="<?php echo __("Terminar Orden de Compra"); ?>" >
<script>
function pregunta()
    {
    var mensaje = 'Son correctos los datos?, BANCO: <?php echo $banco; ?>    CUENTA: <?php echo $cuenta; ?>    CLABE:     ¿Deseas terminar?';
    var opcion = confirm(mensaje);
    if (opcion == true) { 
       //confirmado
        alert('datos procesados !!');
    } else {
        //cancelado
        alert('proceso cancelado !!');
    }
}
```

de esta manera en la variable mensaje armas lo que deseas mostrar en tu mensaje de confirmacion de Javascript, si la opcion es true(verdad) haces lo que deseas en el caso de else es si se cancela el proceso...

Espero te sirva y suerte !!